# The geometric object given by a positive definite symmetric matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

I am wondering what would be the geometric object given by the following equation:

> $(x,y,z)A(x,y,z)^t=1$, where A is a $3\times 3$ positive definite symmetric matrix and t means the transpose of the vectos (x,y,z).

I could not prove it by by checking some cases it seems the solution is an ellipsoid! Any comment?

Comment: Or use the spectral theorem to rewrite the equation explicitly as a sum of squares equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral theorem is your friend as mentioned by @Ted Shifrin in the comments.

Here's a slightly more general overview of such level sets. Let's work in $\Bbb{R}^n$, where we have the standard inner product
\begin{align}
\langle \xi,\eta \rangle:= \sum_{i=1}^k \xi_i \eta_i = \xi^t \eta = \eta^t \xi
\end{align}

Given any matrix $A \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb{R})$, we can always consider the following quadratic function from $\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{align}
\xi \mapsto \langle \xi, A\xi\rangle =\xi^t A\xi = \sum_{i,j=1}^n\xi_j A_{ij} \xi_i
\end{align}
and we can then investigate what its level set $S_1 := \{\xi \in \Bbb{R}^n| \, \, \langle \xi, A\xi\rangle = 1\}$ looks like.

Since you tagged differential geometry, it may be interesting for you to note that if we assume $A$ is invertible then one can use the regular value theorem to quickly prove that $S_1$ is a smooth $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Now, let's only assume that $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Then by the Spectral theorem for real matrices, the matrix $A$ can be orthogonally diagonalized, i.e there exists a diagonal matrix $\Lambda \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb{R})$ (with diagonal entries denoted $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$), and a matrix $P \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb{R})$ which is orthogonal ($P^tP = PP^t = I$, so that $P^{-1} = P^t$) such that
\begin{align}
A = P\Lambda P^{-1} = P \Lambda P^t.
\end{align}

So, now we can write the level set $S_1$ as follows:
\begin{align}
S_1 &= \left\{\xi \in \Bbb{R}^n| \, \left \langle \xi, A \xi\right \rangle = 1\right\} \\
&= \left\{\xi \in \Bbb{R}^n| \, \left \langle \xi, P \Lambda P^t \xi\right \rangle = 1\right\} \\
&= \left\{\xi \in \Bbb{R}^n| \, \left \langle (P^t\xi), \Lambda (P^t \xi)\right \rangle = 1\right\} \\
&= \left\{\eta \in \Bbb{R}^n| \, \left \langle \eta, \Lambda \eta \right \rangle = 1\right\},
\end{align}
(where the last equality follows because $P^t$ is an invertible matrix). So, now, let's write out this last condition more explicitly: $\left \langle \eta, \Lambda \eta \right \rangle = 1$ means that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \eta_i^2 &= 1 \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

---

Let's now investigate this condition in several different cases. Suppose that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite. The positive-definiteness is equivalent to saying that all the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ of $A$ are strictly positive. In this case, we can define $a_i := \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}$, so that $\lambda_i = \dfrac{1}{a_i^2}$, and hence
\begin{align}
1 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \eta_i^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\eta_i^2}{a_i^2}
\end{align}
In this form, the equation may be more recognizable as an $(n-1)$-dimensional ellipsoid in $\Bbb{R}^n$; compare with the familiar equation for an ellipsoid in $\Bbb{R}^3$:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{c^2} = 1
\end{align}

---

I think that should have answered your question, but let me just go on, because I like this question :) Notice that if all the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are equal (equivalently all the $a_i$'s are equal), then the result is an $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere centered at the origin, having radius $a := a_1 = \dots = a_n$.

If we now change hypotheses to: $A$ being symmetric, and invertible (so all the eigenvalues are non-zero) but if we do not make the positive-definiteness assumption, then it means the eigenvalues could have possibly different sign. So, in this case, the resulting level set (assuming it is not empty) will be a certain $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperbola.

---

So really, the take home message is that given a symmetric (and invertible so that everything is nice) matrix $A$, the level set of the quadratic function $\xi \mapsto \langle \xi, A\xi\rangle$ (if not empty) is really an $(n-1)$-dimensional ellipse/hyperbola in disguise. The role of the spectral theorem is to find an orthogonal matrix $P$ (which by reordering its columns if necessary, we may assume has $\det(P) = +1$), which simply means that we should rotate our coordinate system from the $\xi$ coordinares (in your case $\xi = (x,y,z)$) to a new $\eta$ coordinate system where everything is simple and obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the complete solution!